# Polymer 1.0 - iron-ajax not calling url but handling response anyway

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, polymer-1.0

I'm working on a connection element that updates a menu when the connection is granted.

Here is the code for the sign-in element:

```
<dom-module id="sign-in">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">

    <template>
        <paper-card heading="Sign in">
            <div id="sign_in_content" class="card-content">
                <paper-input
                    label="Enter email"
                    value="{{email}}"
                    auto-validate
                    pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.][a-zA-Z]+$"
                    error-message='{{label_wrong_email}}'>
                </paper-input>

                <paper-input
                    label="Enter pass"
                    value="{{pass}}"
                    type="password">
                </paper-input>

                <div class="layout horizontal center-justified">
                    <paper-button raised on-click="sign_in_user">Sign in</paper-button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </paper-card>

        <iron-ajax
            id="sign_in_ajax"
            url="sign_in.php"
            params="{{ajaxParams}}"
            handle-as="json"
            on-response="handleResponse">
        </iron-ajax>
    </template>

    <script>
    Polymer({
        is: "sign-in",

        properties: {
            form: { type: String, value: "sign_in" },
            email: { type: String, value: "" },
            pass: { type: String, value: "" },
            ajaxParams: {
                type: String,
                computed: 'computeParams(form, email, pass)'
            }
        },

        ready: function() {
            console.log('sign-in ready');
        },

        sign_in_user: function()
        {
            console.log("sign-in submit");
            var email   = this.email;
            var pass    = this.pass;

            if (email == '') { alert('You need to submit an e-mail!'); return -1; }
            if (pass == '') { alert('You need to submit a password!'); return -1; }
            this.$.sign_in_ajax.generateRequest();
        },

        computeParams: function(form, email, pass)
        {
            return {
                form  : form,
                email   : email,
                pass    : pass
            };
        },

        handleResponse: function(request)
        {
            console.log("sign-in handleResponse");
            this.result = request.detail.response;
            if (this.result != null)
            {
                if (this.result.status == 0)
                {
                    document.querySelector("ba-menu").update();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

If the user submit the right data, we call the method update of the ba-menu element, which is written as such:

```
<dom-module id="ba-menu">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-menu/paper-submenu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../elements/search-list.html">

  <template>
    <search-list id="ba_menu_search_list" type="menu" result="{{result}}"></search-list>

    <paper-menu>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{result}}">
        <!-- Menu with submenu -->
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{item.submenu}}">
          <paper-submenu>
            <paper-item class="menu-trigger">{{item.name}}</paper-item>
            <paper-menu class="menu-content sublist">
              <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.submenu}}">
                <a href="{{item.suburl}}"><paper-item id="{{item.subid}}">{{item.subname}}</paper-item></a>
              </template>
            </paper-menu>
          </paper-submenu>
        </template>

        <!-- Menu without submenu -->
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{!item.submenu}}">
          <a href="{{item.url}}"><paper-item id="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</paper-item></a>
        </template>

      </template>
    </paper-menu>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "ba-menu",

      properties: {
        result: { type: Object, value: [], notify: true }
      },

      ready: function() {
        console.log("ba-menu ready");
        this.$.ba_menu_search_list.update();
      },

      update: function() {
        console.log("ba-menu update");
        this.$.ba_menu_search_list.update();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

In turn the update() method of the element "search-list" is called. Here is the code for that element:

```
<dom-module id="search-list">
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

    <style>
        :host { display: none; }
    </style>

    <template>
        <iron-ajax
            id="search_list_ajax"
            url="search_list.php"
            params="{{ajaxParams}}"
            handle-as="json"
            on-response="search_list_ajax_response">
        </iron-ajax>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "search-list",

            properties: {
            type:    { type: String, value: "" },
            value:   { type: String, value: "" },
            result:  { type: Object, notify: true },

            ajaxParams: {
                type: String,
                computed: "processParams(type, value)"
            }
          },

            ready: function() {
                console.log("search-list ready");
            },

            update: function() {
                console.log("search-list update");
                this.$.search_list_ajax.generateRequest();
            },

            processParams: function(type, value) {
                return {
                    type    :   type,
                    value       : value
                };
            },

            search_list_ajax_response: function(request)
            {
                console.log("search-list handleResponse");
                this.result = request.detail.response['list'];
                console.log("nb results: "+request.detail.response['list'].length)
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

When a user is not connected, the menu has 3 items, when he's connected, the menu should have 6 items. Here's what I can see in the console:

```
sign-in ready
search-list ready
ba-menu ready
search-list update
search-list handleResponse
nb results: 3
sign-in submit
sign-in handleResponse
cookie id=4c3280b189c746e86de4
ba-menu update
search-list update
search-list handleResponse
nb results: 3
```

We can see the call following the sign in and the retrieval of the cookie id from sign_in.php.
Then we see the search-list "update" and "handleResponse", yet search_list.php hasn't been called. I know that for a fact since I have a php function that logs any call to that file. Add to this the fact that in the database I'm successfully connected and thus should get a nb results of 6.
If I wait a bit and then refresh, the menu shows the 6 desired items.

I really don't understand how handleResponse get called and how the response can be different from null since the php file hasn't been parsed!

Anyone has an idea?
Thanks in advance!

Jere

Comment: Open your browser console, go to Network, reload your page/code, see if search_list is indeed not called, which won't be the case imo.

Comment: I can see a call to search_list.php tagged as "cached".
That explains how I can see an answer and no real call...

Is there a way to force the call without using the cache ?

Comment: append a dummy random value as a get parameter, like "search_list.php?dummyParam="+Math.random()*Math.random()", which will produce something like "search_list.php?dummyParam=1.8554845877" and force browser to avoid cache (there is still issue with this on some versions of Safari tho I think)

Comment: @SecularKid : Thanks! I modified my code accordingly and it works better now. To the Polymer team, a little boolean cache attribute for the iron-ajax element could be nice! ;-)